# Nginx/OpenResty in Docker - 99: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, nginx, openresty

I have an nginx proxy based on openresty (https://openresty.org/en/), which is running in a docker container. It's simple proxy like:

```
        proxy_pass https://foobarstorage1.z6.web.core.windows.net/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
```

From time to time, we get an error like bellow and I have no idea how to debug it.

It cannot be reproduced but it happens from time to time and I have the feeling it might have something with IPV6 but I am not 100% sure.

```
2021/12/20 13:10:28 [crit] 21794#21794: *20 connect() to [2606:4700::6812:f458]:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address), client: 172.17.0.1, server: ddyntest.ddns.net, request: "GET /elearn/preview.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "ddyntest.ddns.net:9443"
```

Any tips are welcomed.